# Do I need a Schengen Visa or with an invitation letter is enough?

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, spain

My wife asks me if with an invitation letter from Spain his father (peruvian) can travel with us to Italy since we wanted to visit plus his father dreamed to see Italy.

Here in Spain I know I can make an invitation letter so he can stay here, but I don't know if he can travel to another country from Europe, Italy in this case. Should I make him a Schengen visa or isn't needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peru is on the list of countries whose nationals do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area (relatively recent addition, after most of South America, if memory serves). Generally speaking, if you can enter Spain without a visa, you can almost always visit other Schengen countries (including Italy).

If your father is travelling with you from Spain to Italy, there shouldn't be any police check and I would not expect any questioning whatsoever.

If your father is travelling straight to Italy to join you there, presenting an invitation letter from a Spanish resident would be a bit odd. Instead, he should just explain the holiday plans you have and perhaps have some documentation regarding the accommodation you arranged (hotel booking, etc.)

Comment: Note that like any Annex II national, one must be able to convince immigration officers that one will leave the Schengen Area at the end of their stay (a maximum of 90 days out of 180) and of course have the resources for the stay without working (though this can be through family members taking care of the costs). For reference, Peru joined the Annex II list in 2016.

Comment: @jcaron: I don't know how they are doing things post-COVID, but pre-COVID, I traveled to Europe several times on a US passport and the border guards barely said three words to me. I get the sense that they have better things to do than bother random Annex II visitors about the details of their visits, but maybe they treat other countries differently to the US. Or maybe I just got lucky.

Comment: @Kevin the fact that you need to be able to prove it does not mean they have to interrogate everyone in detail, like you needing a drivers license to drive doesn’t mean there will be a cop checking every morning. They have a number of clues on which they rely to decide whether to push things further or not. But some Annex II visitors, including visitors from “rich” countries like the US or Canada, are regularly refused entry and sent back home.